# How to bring a specific child on the front in horizontal layout in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, layout, gameobject

So basically I have a hand with cards. Those cards are gameobject prefab and when I hover one it scale bigger and slightly move upward. But when scaling it overlap the card at his left and stay behind the one at his right, and I want the card to get over the cards instead.

I tried to change the z index and the layer but all cards in hand are ruled by the same horizontal layout...

Should I just push the cards on each side of the hovered one ? Or someone have a solution to draw a specific child in front of the others ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to dynamically add a new Canvas to your object that you want to be in front, and override sorting:

[image]

In code, you can do something like this:

```
var newCanvas = yourGameObject.AddComponent<Canvas>();
newCanvas.overrideSorting = true;
newCanvas.sortingOrder = 1; // this has to be higher than order of parent canvas
```

Of course you should remember to remove this canvas when it's not needed anymore.

Edit: updated the solution with full code that I verified to be working. What I missed was adding the raycaster to the new canvas. This is the full code:

```
public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerEnterHandler
{
    private Canvas tempCanvas;
    private GraphicRaycaster tempRaycaster;

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // add and configure necessary components
        tempCanvas = gameObject.AddComponent<Canvas>();
        tempCanvas.overrideSorting = true;
        tempCanvas.sortingOrder = 1;
        tempRaycaster = gameObject.AddComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();
        
        // your operations on the object
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(1.1f, 1.1f);
        // ...
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // remove components that are not needed anymore
        Destroy(tempRaycaster);
        Destroy(tempCanvas);
        
        // your operations on the object
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(1f, 1f);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to add a canvas but it seems to remove and interrupt any pointer events, do you know if its the correct behaviour ? Maybe I've done it wrong ?
My gameobjects have multiple pointer events that I need to keep active, like dragging the card. I just want the object to be displayed on front of the others that are in the same horizontal layout.

Comment: Hey Tanguy, sorry for not coming back to you earlier. When you add a new canvas you also need to add new raycaster for events to work correctly. Updated the answer to show full code. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah I'm kinda new to Unity and raycast thing ... I should have find this out, but I really appreciate your help that was exactly the behaviour I wanted !